# I can't vagrant up because of SSH error while mounting shared folder

Tags: chef, vagrant

This is the error code I'm receiving:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` v-csc-1 /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
```

and this is what my Vagrantfile looks like:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-lucid-32"

  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

  config.vm.share_folder "mysite.de", "/var/www/mysite.de", "../data"

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "apache2"
    chef.add_recipe "php"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql"
    chef.add_recipe "vim"
    chef.add_recipe "git"
    chef.add_recipe "openssl"
    chef.json = { :mysql_password => "whatever" }
  end
end
```

Extra info: I'm using OS X Lion as my host machine.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem but only with a CentOS 5.7 x86_64.box

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and it turned out my chef.cookbooks_path didn't exist. In your case does a directory called '/cookbooks' exist on your host machine? Do you mean to set the path to a root level directory?

If you have a sub-directory called 'cookbooks' within the directory you're executing vagrant from, you should use this value instead (without leading slash):

chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"